# Tableau - Filter Buttons not filtering correctly

Tags: visualization, data-analysis, graphs, tableau

I created filter buttons to use as a filter for 6 category's (measures) in Tableau Public (latest version) so when you click on them the values for each display on my "Military Enrollment By Branch & War Films" graph on my Dashboard. However, what is happening is that when I click on one of the buttons it displays the values for each category but only for some of the years such as 1980 or 1981-1983 whereas it should be displaying all the values across all years on the x-axis (from 1980-2021). It should also be displaying the one button category that I chose but it shows me the values for 4 category's. The buttons are not working correctly and I can't find out why it is doing this.

Attached is the workbook:
https://public.tableau.com/views/LastOne_16419877017470/Dashboard?:language=en-US&publish=yes&:display_count=n&:origin=viz_share_link

Example of what it shows when I click on "Marines":
[image]

When I click on "Army" and so on:
[image]

Comment: Where is your 'category--all' - once I click a branch of the service, I can't get back to others.

Comment: Maybe you have your filters stuck, so when it filters to service branch it also filters to a specific year?